# lbl: break lbl; in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Apparently, `lbl: break lbl;` is perfectly valid in JavaScript (but not `lbl: continue lbl;`).

Is there any obscure use for this construct?

Comment: Just for information, `lbl: continue lbl;` is not valid because `continue` is only permitted within a loop.

Comment: And `lbl: break lbl;` just breaks out of itself, so it's roughly equivalent to `;`.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm curious. I thought that `break` was only permitted within a loop too. What does it do outside a loop?

Comment: @Oriol Break outside a block scope: `lbl: {break lbl;alert('Hey, never reached!');}`

Comment: @Oriol: You can also use it to terminate a `case` block (to prevent fall-through) or any labeled block of code.

Comment: There are lots of valid but useless statements in JavaScript (and probably any programming language).

Comment: @RobW Thanks, I didn't know that's possible. BoltClock: I knew that it can be used inside switch, but I thought that only loops could be labeled, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a label before any statment. `continue` is only allowed inside loops (for, for-in, while, do-while) as already said by [boltclock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/) in the comments to the question. `break` can be used inside loops, switch-statements, and any statement (as already commented by [rob-w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/)).

```
lbl: break lbl;
```

The above statement is valid. As already commented by [frederic-hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/frederic-hamidi) "it breaks out of itself" and isn't very useful by itself, but see example below of how it could be useful.

```
lbl: continue lbl;
```

The above statement is invalid because it isn't a loop.

An example of how **break** ***label*** could be used in a block:

```
function test() {
  var x='';
  lb1: {
    x+='1';
    if(x.length >2) break lb1;
    x+='2';
  }
  lb2: {
    x+='3';
    if(x.length >2) break lb2; //Can't break to lb1 because it isn't inside this block
    x+='4';
  }
  console.log(x);
}

test();
```

Outputs:

> 123

This is an example of how **break** ***label*** could be used inside a loop:

```
outer: for(var idxo=0; idxo < 5;++idxo) {
  inner: for(var idxi=0; idxi < 5;++idxi) {
    if (idxi==3) break outer;
    console.log(idxo,idxi);
  }
}
```

Outputs:

> 0 0, 0 1, 0 2

This is an example of how **continue** ***label*** could be used inside a loop:

```
outer: for(var idxo=0; idxo < 5;++idxo) {
  inner: for(var idxi=0; idxi < 5;++idxi) {
    if (idxi==3) continue outer;
    console.log(idxo,idxi);
  }
}
```

Outputs:

> 0 0, 0 1, 0 2, 1 0, 1 1, 1 2, 2 0, 2 1, 2 2, 3 0, 3 1, 3 2, 4 0, 4 1, 4 2

[ECMA262:5 12.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

> 12.12 Labelled Statements
>
> **Syntax**
>
> LabelledStatement :
>
> Identifier : Statement
>
> **Semantics**
>
> A Statement may be prefixed by a label. Labelled statements are only used in conjunction with labelled break and continue statements. ECMAScript has no goto statement.
>
> An ECMAScript program is considered syntactically incorrect if it contains a LabelledStatement that is enclosed by a LabelledStatement with the same Identifier as label. This does not apply to labels appearing within the body of a FunctionDeclaration that is nested, directly or indirectly, within a labelled statement.
>
> The production Identifier : Statement is evaluated by adding Identifier to the label set of Statement and then evaluating Statement. If the LabelledStatement itself has a non-empty label set, these labels are also added to the label set of Statement before evaluating it. If the result of evaluating Statement is (break, V, L) where L is equal to Identifier, the production results in (normal, V, empty).
>
> Prior to the evaluation of a LabelledStatement, the contained Statement is regarded as possessing an empty label set, unless it is an IterationStatement or a SwitchStatement, in which case it is regarded as possessing a label set consisting of the single element, empty.